# Example using Twilio in an RPG program on IBM AS400 to send a text message

Tags: twilio, ibm-midrange, rpgle

Does anyone have a working example of sending an SMS text message using the REST API in Twilio from an RPGLE program on the AS400?

I'm doing a HTTP Post using an API that results in a TIME OUT message.

Comment: There might not be any examples, but I would find an example of calling a REST API and use that as a starting point. Otherwise, post your code (minus the API authentication) so we can see what is going wrong.

Comment: This presentation by Scott Klement has an example on how to consume a REST web service.  http://www.scottklement.com/presentations/Web%20Services%20for%20RPGers.pdf